# RAILS: Save Each Collection Check Box on A Form as Its Own Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to Rails and I'm working on a pretty large, fairly complicated project for a friend as a way to challenge myself. (Hey, go big or go home right?).

A little background: The project is essentially an horse riding competition event management platform from scratch that can manage everything from registrations to scoring at the event.

The expected flow of this is as follows:

- User signs up for the platform and creates a profile.
- Inside the platform are multiple shows (added by an admin).
- Each show has multiple events.
- Each event within a show has multiple divisions (declared when creating the show).
- User (after signing up) logs in and clicks on a show they want to register for.
- On the registration form for the show:
  --- They check the boxes for each event they want to participate in for that show. ***
  --- For each event they select, they choose what division of that event they want to participate in from a drop down.
  --- In a text box they enter the name of the horse they plan on riding for each event within that show.
- On the day of the show:
  --- Each division of each event has a score "page" that pre-populates who registered for that event's division along with text boxes for an admin to enter scores each participant receives.

I have the following models created:

- user.rb (created using Devise gem)
- show.rb
- division.rb
- event.rb
- register.rb
- score.rb (to be created)

Here are my current association models:
user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :shows, through: :registers
  has_many :events, through: :registers
  has_many :divisions, through: :registers
  has_many :registers
end
```

show.rb

```
class Show < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :divisions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :registers
  has_many :users, through: :registers
end
```

division.rb

```
class Division < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :show
  belongs_to :event, :optional => true
  has_many :registers
  has_many :users, through: :registers
end
```

event.rb

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :show
  has_many :registers
  has_many :users, through: :registers
  has_many :divisions
end
```

register.rb

```
class Register < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :show
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :events
  has_many :divisions
end
```

The *** in the workflow is where I am stuck at. I feel like the best way to make the score pages work is to have each selected event check box save as it's own object to the "registers" db, which is why I haven't created the scores model yet until I figure this out. I'm thinking it's probably an association problem and that I might not be thinking through my associations correctly. Associations has been a bit of a murky subject for me to grasp appropriately.

Any help/feedback/thoughts are welcome. Also, please let me know if I need to share any controllers, forms, etc. to help better help or understand the issue. Thanks so much!

P.S. - Please be gentle with comments as, like I stated before, I'm still learning the ins and outs of Rails. :-)

**UPDATE:**
Adding screenshot of what I'm trying to do: [screenshot of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3rGl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your app design is not really complex but it is a bit bloated to me. (which doesn't necessarily mean it wouldn't work the way you have done it)

Here few points :

1 - The show is really an inverted tree structure. **Show** has many **Events** has many **Divisions**. For this reason I would not make divisions a child of Show as you have declared here :

division.rb

```
class Division < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :show
  belongs_to :event, :optional => true
  has_many :registers
  has_many :users, through: :registers
end
```

We already know the divisions are child of events and we can climb up to the show if needed.

For example let's say you have loaded a specific division (the first one) and we want the show it belongs, we can climb up easily this way :

```
@division = Division.first
@show_for_this_division = @division.event.show
```

2 - Now the bookings. I think you have called the bookings **Registers**. If you don't need any validation I would suggest to use a joint table `has_and_belongs_to_many`. You have used `has_many through:` which is fine too if you need to store data for the joint value. Which can be the case if you want to handle scores (maybe you can add a **score** column to the **Register** model).

**Register** will behave like a joint table between the **users** and the **Show** tree.

For this reason I think **Register** should belong to only two tables : **Division** and **User**. **Divison** is the real physical atomic event people will take part in (People don't really take part in the **Show** or **Event**, they dispute **Division** with their horse, if I am not mistaken).

So basicaly to me **Register** should look like this :

```
class Register < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :division
  belongs_to :user  
end
```

And to make the relationship between the Show / event / division tree and the users, just make the following into **User** and **Division**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 ...
  has_many :divisions, through: :registers
 ...
end

class Division < ApplicationRecord
  ..
  has_many :users, through: :registers
  ..
end
```

Which you have done properly. But all other `has_many through:` relationships seem redundant. (Unless you need them later but you need to feel the need for it to use it. Deciding from the start you need more `has_many through:` than those for the joins table **Register** is a bit too *optimistic*)

***Conclusion***

So basically just make 1 tree for the Show/Event/division with simple `belongs_to` and `has_many` and your model **User** should have only one real child : `Register` and a convenient `through` to the division :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  
  has_many :divisions, through: :registers
  has_many :registers
end
```

If you ever need to access information for each division belonging to a specific user, you can still climb up the tree easily.

Regarding the registration process, you should only display the divisions (which are the events the riders take part in and for which they will receive a score).
In order to make your form more friendly you can group up divisions by events. This won't be easy if there are many events and many divisions for each event.
You could also display links to `events/index` that would display all divisions for a specific event and allow for users to pick some divisions inside this specific event.

Comment: Hey @Maxence, that was very helpful and I've restructured like you recommended. However, I am still stuck at my original point. As you mentioned, I have broken it out where each event is listed and that's where the registrant selects what division and enters a horse name for that event/division (if they choose to participate in that event). But, I'm trying to save each division/horse name entry pair as it's own record entry in the DB. Essentially, each event they register for by selecting a division and entering a horse name becomes a record in the DB. But I want to do this using one form to..

Comment: ..make it easy for the registrant instead of having to click through multiple forms to register for each event/division within a show. Does that make sense? I've linked a screenshot on my original post to show what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It depends first where you make it happen ? Do you have a registers controller on top of the Register model ? If you have you probably have to make a custom action. Because the default `new` action would be to create a single record at a time. But basically you have to make a form pointing to a specific `create` action. And inside this form, loop through every Division item and add a field for this specific division (the division_id then) and a field for the horse name. The only missing field is the user_id that you can get from Devise: current_user.

Comment: Maybe you can start to implement something and ask a new question when you have an issue with this form as it is a bit broad at this stage to advise anything further.